# click on image to display text and click again to remove text

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the toggle feature and I'm able to click on the image to display and remove the text. However, when the page initially loads the text is already displayed. I want the text to be initially hidden, but I'm not sure why the hidden class isn't working in CSS.

```js
$('.Figure').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.overlay').toggle();
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: hidden;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* opacity: 1; */
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Figure">
  <div class="hidden">
    <img class="pics" src="photos/image1.JPG" />
    <div class="overlay ">
      <p1 class="text "> xxxx</p1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Figure ">
  <div class="hidden ">
    <img class="pics " src="photos/mel.jpeg " />
    <div class="overlay ">
      <p1 class="text "> xxx </p1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `display: none`, Also note you have an extra `"` in `src="photos/image1.JPG" " `

Answer (score 0):

As @Carsten Løvbo Andersen said use `display: none` in `.overlay` instead of `display: hidden`. You can check below, its working.

```js
$('.Figure').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.overlay').toggle();
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* opacity: 1; */
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Figure">
  <div class="hidden">
    <img class="pics" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <div class="overlay ">
      <p1 class="text "> xxxx</p1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Figure ">
  <div class="hidden ">
    <img class="pics " src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <div class="overlay ">
      <p1 class="text "> xxx </p1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```